# javascript quiz help needed

Tags: javascript, html

so basicaly my problem is that i need the submit button to pop-up a new window, containing the score and the right answers. Heres what i tried to do, which doesnt work:
**(body code):**

```
<form id="textcont" name="htmltest" onSubmit="return checkAll() && results()">
<b>1) Τι σημαίνει HTML?</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" onclick="score[1]=0">a) Home Tool Markup Language<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" onclick="score[1]=0">b) Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" onclick="score[1]=1">c) Hyper Text Markup Language<br>

<b>2) Διάλεξε το σωστό HTML tag για την μεγαλύτερη επικεφαλίδα:</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" onclick="score[2]=0">a) < h6 ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" onclick="score[2]=0">b) < head ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" onclick="score[2]=1">c) < h1 ><br>

<b>3) Ποιο είναι το σωστό HTML tag για line break?</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" onclick="score[3]=0">a) < break ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" onclick="score[3]=0">b) < lb ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" onclick="score[3]=1">c) < br ><br>

<b>4) Διάλεξε το σωστό HTML tag για να κάνεις bold κάποια γράμματα:</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" onclick="score[4]=0">a) < bold ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" onclick="score[4]=1">b) < b ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="c" onclick="score[4]=0">c) < text.bold ><br>

<b>5) Ποιος είναι ο σωστός τρόπος για να δημιουργήσετε έναν υπερσύνδεσμο;</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" onclick="score[5]=0">a) < a url="http://www.unipi.gr">Unipi.gr < / a><br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" onclick="score[5]=1">b) < a href="http://www.unipi.gr">Unipi.gr< / a><br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" onclick="score[5]=0">c) < a >http://www.unipi.gr"< / a><br>

<b>6) Ποια απο τα παρακάτω HTML tag απευθύνονται όλα σε πίνακα?</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="a" onclick="score[6]=0">a) < table >, < head >, < tfoot ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="b" onclick="score[6]=0">b) < table >, < tr >, < tt ><br>
<input type="radio" name="q6" value="c" onclick="score[6]=1">c) < table >, < tr> , < td ><br>

<input type="submit" value="Αξιολόγηση"> <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br><br>
</form>
```

**javascript file:**

```
function checkAll()
{
    var oops = "";
    for ( var q = 1; q <= 6; ++q )
    {
        var rbs = document.htmltest["q" + q];
        var okay = false;
        for ( var r = 0; r < rbs.length; ++r )
        {
            if ( rbs[r].checked ) okay = true;
        }
        if ( ! okay ) oops += "," + q;
    }
    if ( oops != "" )
    {
        alert("Δεν απαντήσατε στις εξής ερωτήσεις: " + oops.substring(1) +"\n Παρακαλώ απαντήστε σε όλες τις ερωτήσεις.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var score = new Array;
function results()
{
var i, total;
total = 0;
for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
total += score[i];
}
window=window.open("resultshtml.html","answers","width=400px,height=700px");
}
```

**and resultshtml.html file:**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">
<head>
    <title>html test results</title>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var total = window.opener.total;
document.write(total);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

unfortunately, document.write in the last window returns "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two problems that I see:

- You must define `total` in the global scope so `window.opener` can access it.
- Since the form is being submitted, the page is reloaded and `score`, `total` and all other variables will return to their initial state. So you have to stop the form submition: `return false` on function `results`.

Notes:

The way you modify score from the radio inputs is not good. You better use the `value` attribute to convey information:

```
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" onclick="score[2]=1">...
vs
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="2,1">...

# iterate over selected inputs
var pair = selected_input.value.split(",")
var key = pair[0], value = pair[1];
score[key] = value;
```

And you better define `score` as an object and iterate over it with `(for key in score) { score[key] ... }`

But anyway, why don't you run your JS code in the parent page?

```
new_window = window.open("resultshtml.html","answers","width=400px,height=700px");
new_window.document.write(total);
```

If you prefer this code to be in the popup window, then create a function there and call it from the parent with the required info (`score` in this case). In any of these cases you won't depend whether the parent page is reloaded or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
function results()
{
var i, total;
```

This declares `total` as a local variable, which cannot be accessed from the other window. You can fix that (making it a global variable) by removing that part from the `var` statement (and optionally putting a new `var` statement for the variable outside of any functions).

As a side note, you should use the `&lt;` and `&gt;` escape codes for the less/greater than signs within the form. That would eliminate the need to insert spaces and make it more valid HTML.

Comment: thx for the side note, much appreciated. Total still doesnt work though, if i move var total=0; before the function, all im getting in the new window is 0, because the function doesnt calculate the score like it did before. Therefore i think i need a new way to do it :S

Answer (score 1):

Try removing total from the `var i, total;` declaration? I think it creates a local scoped variable this way.

Comment: still getting the same, the problem probably has to do with my coding, since i just started learning. I think the whole results() function is wrong. maybe a new way to calculate the score?

Comment: Try using the debugger.  Firebug for Firefox and Chrome Debugger for Chrome.  If you put console.info("a log statement"); throughout your code you can track down the bugs and see what the values of variables are at certain points.  The debuggers can also do this for you too :)  Good luck!

Comment: Ah. you're not setting the `score` variable anywhere.